# does max_connect_errors not check Aborted_connects?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL (5.5) which status var reflects the current number of connection errors that are compared against [`max_connect_errors`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connect_errors) by the server? I thought it was [`Aborted_connects`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_connects) but in my testing I can still connect to server after driving aborted_connects (in succession) well above `max_connect_errors`...

Asked differently, does mysql server check `aborted_connects` against any threshold variable? Is any behavior dependent on value of that status variable (or is just FYI for DBAs)?

**EDIT 1**

to clarify, I am less interested in how to reach `max_connect_errors`, and more in whether having a high `aborted_connects` will have any negative consequences.

**For context:**
we're using a layer 4 (TCP) load balancer to distribute JDBC connections of appservers' db connection pools across a cluster of MySQL read-only slaves. The load balancer (AWS ELB) has a TCP-based health check feature - it periodically checks health of the db servers by establishing a TCP connection with db server's mysql port. Since the LB does not speak 'JDBC', literally all it does is create a TCP connection and immediately disconnect. Each of these connections, however, increment `aborted_connects` on mysqld. I see no other side-effects, but wonder whether running up `aborted_connects` will eventually have negative consequences (for example, mysqld will ban the LB's IP, thus causing health check failures)

Thank you,
-nikita

Comment: How are you testing? Is it localhost (unix socket) or over tcp (127.0.0.1 or other) ?

Comment: 'telnet remoteHost 3306' and CTRL+C - more times than max_connect_errors; then do a proper connect using mysql.

Comment: try connecting with incorrect login info for more than `max_connect_errors`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`max_connect_errors` is on a per-host basis, so I doubt that it checks a status variable such as `Aborted_connects`.

This variable probably does not apply if you are testing using 'localhost' (which does not use TCP), for what happens if you lock localhost out? No one could connect (assuming a single root user and not being able to log in root remotely)!

So I felt like digging into the source on this one. In the file 'sql/hostname.cc' is a function `ip_to_hostname`. This function has the following comments (emphasis mine):

> Resolve IP-address to host name.
>
> This function does the following things:
>       - resolves IP-address;
>       - employs Forward Confirmed Reverse DNS technique to validate IP-address;
>       - returns host name if IP-address is validated;
>       - set value to out-variable connect_errors -- this variable represents the
>         number of connection errors from the specified IP-address.
>
> NOTE: **connect_errors are counted (are supported) only for the clients
>     where IP-address can be resolved and FCrDNS check is passed.**

There is also this comment with regards to localhost (or loopback ip like 127.0.0.1):

```
*connect_errors= 0; /* Do not count connect errors from localhost. */
```

Furthermore, the only time connect_errors is incremented is in the function 'inc_host_errors' of the same sql/hostname.cc file. This is only called from the sql/sql_acl.cc file. It looks like these are some of the situations:

1) There is an error with the packets (packet lengths don't match). This is also probably why the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blocked-host.html) says:

> If you get the Host 'host_name' is blocked error message for a given host, you should first verify that there is nothing wrong with TCP/IP connections from that host. If you are having network problems, it does you no good to increase the value of the max_connect_errors variable.

2) Invalid native password (function is `native_password_authenticate`)

3) Invalid old-style password (function is `old_password_authenticate`)

I might have missed a few things, but ultimately, `max_connect_errors` has nothing to do with aborted connections, but rather networking issues or invalid passwords.

---

For completion sake, I will mention I was looking at the Percona 5.5.15-rel21 source code.

---

So, what does `Aborted_connects` have to do with it? Well, according to [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/communication-errors.html), it gets incremented anytime:

- A client does not have privileges to connect to a database.
- A client uses an incorrect password.
- A connection packet does not contain the right information.
- It takes more than connect_timeout seconds to get a connect packet.

So, `Aborted_connects` is just an indicator for a DBA to know there *might* be a problem (eg: if it increases dramatically over a period of time, someone might be attempting to hack into the server, but you should be protected by `max_connect_errors` in this case).

If yours increases steadily from the healthchecks, you can still use it if it spikes abnormally.

Comment: thanks so much for sleuthing. Sounds like `aborted_connects` is basically just a statistic - not used by mysqld to determine server behavior. I clarified the intent of the question - would love to know if you change your answer after reading.

Comment: @Nikita I added a bit more, but it is basically a status variable that indicates one of the above 4 issues. Which you may or may not find useful :)